# Building a REST web service using Mono and C#

Tags: c#, mono, restful-architecture

This is my first time building a REST Web Service using C# and Mono. Mono's guide to [Writing a Web Service](http://www.mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService) doesn't show how I can have separate handlers for the following resources:

```
http://myhost/api/v1/user?query=string
http://myhost/api/v1/user/{userid}?query=string
```

I did see an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29706/REST-Web-Services-in-ASP-NET-C) about using the interface IHttpHandler to accomodate my requirements but that was written in 2008.

Does anyone have any pointers, or even better example code on how I can elegantly achieve the above by using Mono libraries.